# How can I programmatically in .NET translate a color code number from 0 to 140 into RBG codes?

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, rgb

How can I programmatically in .NET translate a color code number from 0 to 140 into RBG codes for blue through yellow?
Color code of 0 should translate to indigo blue, and 140 translate to yellow, as per plot below.  Looks like green is in the middle.

COLOR CODE NUMBER TO COLOR RANGE

I need to translate the number on the right (0-140ish) to the adjacent color to the left.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Break your scale into four sections. As the color scale increases, section 1 is red/blue with red diminishing, section 2 is blue/green with green intensifying, section 3 is blue/green with blue diminishing, and section 4 is green/red with red intensifying.

Untested sample below. You may need to make adjustments depending on the required layout of your RGB value.

```
private static readonly double n35 = 35;

public static int CalculateRgb(byte colorIndex)
{
    if (colorIndex > 140)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(colorIndex));
    }

    byte red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

    if (colorIndex <= 35)
    {
        blue = 255
        red = 255 * (n35 - (double) colorIndex) / n35);
    }
    else if (colorIndex <= 70)
    {
        colorIndex -= 35;

        blue = 255
        green = 255 * ((double) colorIndex / 35);
    }
    else if (colorIndex <= 105)
    {
        colorIndex -= 70;

        green = 255
        blue = 255 * (n35 - (double) colorIndex) / n35);
    }
    else
    {
        colorIndex -= 105;

        green = 255
        red = 255 * ((double) colorIndex) / n35);
    }

    return
        (red << 24) |
        (green << 16) |
        (blue << 8);
}
```

Comment: I will try this!